# MySQL Left Join more than once

Tags: mysql, join

I have a Table like this:

Data:

```
id | state | more
-----------------
1  | 1     | ...
2  | 2     | ...
3  | 1     | ...
```

and States:

```
id | state
----------
1  | Open
2  | Closed
```

If I do

```
SELECT states.state FROM data LEFT JOIN states ON data.state = states.id
```

I receive

```
state
-----
Open
Closed
Open
```

So far so good. What I am trying to do (without success) is, if I have a table Data like this:

```
id | state | state2 | more
--------------------------
1  | 1     | 2      | ...
2  | 2     | 1      | ...
3  | 1     | 1      | ...
```

How do I get:

```
state  | state 2
----------------
Open   | Closed 
Closed | Open
Open   | Open
```

Comment: What is 'more'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT states.state, states2.state
FROM data
LEFT JOIN states as states ON data.state = states.id
LEFT JOIN states as states2 ON data.state2 = states2.id
```

Comment: table states2  DOESN`T exists

Comment: @PhilHarmonie Try now

Answer (score 1):

Just use another `LEFT JOIN` and `alias`

```
SELECT 
   s1.state AS state1
   s2.state AS state2 
FROM data d
LEFT JOIN states s1 ON d.state = s1.id
LEFT JOIN states s2 ON d.state2 = s2.id
```

Comment: This is not working but I'm still getting "You have an error in your SQL syntax...". I already added the missing as's

Comment: sorry I forget set d.state (2)  to d.state2

Answer (score 0):

You would need to do another left join

```
SELECT 
   s1.state AS state1,
   s2.state AS state2 
FROM data d
LEFT JOIN states s1 ON d.state = s1.id
LEFT JOIN states s2 ON d.state2 = s2.id
```

Comment: table states2 DOESN`T exists